# Count number of products with no sells in a time period

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, office365, unique

I have to enter the amount of sales per month for each product. But if a product doesn't sell for 6 consecutive months, it becomes inactive, and I no longer put its sales on the table.

I would need to know the total number of different active products, which have not been sold within this 6 month period.

My formula is returning a total of "2"(bananas and apples) as a total, but as "banana" became inactive, the correct number would be "1" (only apples).

[image]

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Product Name;Product Status per month="NO SALE")*(Month<=$G1)*(Month>=EDATE($G1;-5))*(StatusActivity>0))))
```

Comment: What is in `G1`? Also, do you meant `Date` where you wrote `Month`? Otherwise the `EDATE()` function doesn't make much sense as you would just subtract 5 months from the current month.

Comment: Can a product that is inactive subsequently become active?  In other words, could Banana have become inactive in February, but then become active again in May?